# construct xml using multiple inputs

Tags: java, apache-camel, xslt-2.0, jbossfuse, smooks

We have a use case where we need to construct master xml from multiple sources. Initially we will get an xml from service and using information from this  xml we make different Data base calls to save/get information and finally construct master xml and save to database. We are using camel with Fuse.

```
Here is our xml and camel routes.

        <xml>
            <xmlInformation>
               .....
            </xmlInformation>
            <customers>
                  <customer>...</customer>
                  <customer>...</customer>
                  <customer>...</customer>
            </customers>
             <products>
              <product>....<product>
              <product>....<product>
              <product>....<product>
                </products>
        </xml>
```

Number of customer and product elements is dynamic and we extract each customer, product from xml, save to database and get some customer,product related ids and construct master xml as below.

```
    <m:master>
          <m:xmlInformation>....</m:xmlInformation>
          <c:customers>
              <c:customer id="12345">....</c:customer>
              <c:customer id="22345">....</c:customer>
              <c:customer id="32345">....</c:customer>
          </c:customers>
          <p:products>
               <p:product id="22222">.....</p:product>
                <p:product id="11111">.....</p:product>
                <p:product id="33333">.....</p:product>
          </p:products>
    </m:master>

Here is came route

   <route id="routeA">
    <from uri="direct-vm:saveMasterXml" />
    <setProperty propertyName="originalIUPayload"><simple>${body}</simple></setProperty>
    <splitter parallelProcessing=true stopOnException=true strategyRef="customersAggregator" >
         <xpath>/xml/customers/customer</xpath>
          <bean ref="customerService" method="saveCustomer" />
    </splitter>
     <setProperty propertyName="customerXmls"><simple>${body}</simple></setProperty>
    <setBody><simple>${property.originalIUPayload}</simple></setBody>
 <splitter parallelProcessing=true stopOnException=true strategyRef="productsAggregator" >
         <xpath>/xml/products/product</xpath>
          <bean ref="productService" method="getProductIds" />
    </splitter>
   <setProperty propertyName="productIds"><simple>${body}</simple></setProperty>
    <setBody><simple>${property.originalIUPayload}</simple></setBody>
     <!-- transformation -->
     <bean ref="masterService" method="saveMasterXml" />
    </route>
```

Output of customer's splitter is list of customer xmls enriched with ids and output of product splitter is list of product ids. Can i use xslt to construct master xml as most of elements for master xml is of original xml but ids from customers and product list needs to be passed to xslt. I am stuck here to solve it. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I used .splitter() and then .end(), then again you get the original message.

Since you are saving to a database, you would probably want a .transacted() before the splitting. Take a look in the book "Camel In Action" for more info about transactions.

And instead of logging the body of the splitted message you could call the bean for customer or product

See example:

```
import org.apache.camel.EndpointInject;
import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SplittingToXSLT extends CamelTestSupport {

    @EndpointInject(uri = "direct:start")
    private ProducerTemplate start;

    @Test
    public void testName() throws Exception {
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("direct:start")
                    .split(xpath("/xml/customers/customer | /xml/products/product"))
                    .choice()
                    .when(xpath("/customer"))
                        .log("Customer ${body}")
                    .when(xpath("/product"))
                        .log("Product ${body}")
                    .end()
                    .log("${body}")
                .to("xslt:test.xsl")
                .log("${body}")
                ;
            }
        });
        start.sendBody("<xml>\n" +
            "  <xmlInformation>\n" +
            "  </xmlInformation>\n" +
            "  <customers>\n" +
            "    <customer>1</customer>\n" +
            "    <customer>2</customer>\n" +
            "  </customers>\n" +
            "  <products>\n" +
            "    <product>3</product>\n" +
            "    <product>4</product>\n" +
            "  </products>\n" +
            "</xml>");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }

}
```

I dont know how namespace in xslt works, but here's an example without:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <master>
      <xmlInformation>
        <xsl:value-of select="/xml/xmlInformation"/>
      </xmlInformation>
      <customers>
        <xsl:for-each select="/xml/customers/customer">
          <customer>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:attribute>
          </customer>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </customers>
      <products>
        <xsl:for-each select="/xml/products/product">
          <product>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:attribute>
          </product>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </products>
    </master>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```